# Spring Boot Executable JAR - Layout Changes break Classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that allows the loading of additional components from the class path (if they are subclasses of an interface defined in my application). This worked great in Spring Boot 1.3.8, however I would like to upgrade to Spring Boot 1.4.2 but the [new layout of executable JARs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#executable-jar-layout) is causing some issues.

When I now run my application with an additional JAR on the class path, I get a ClassNotFoundException for the interface I'm trying to subclass. This suggests to me that although the application knows where my classes are in BOOT-INF, because they are not in a standard location the additional components can't find them.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

I have tried the different layout options in spring-boot-maven-plugin, but none of them seem to do what I want.

Comment: Setting classpath through [`loader.path`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-launching) application property instead of JVM options `-cp`.

Comment: I've tried that, but the Component Scan doesn't seem to pick up the components in the additional JARs (I can't tell if the components could then find the interface as they're not being picked up to check!). I tried setting it on the command line (`-Dloader.path=...`) and through application.properties but in neither case did it pick up my additional components.

Comment: Did you set the `loader.path` in the right format? It is a comma-separated list, unlike java `-cp` which uses `:` or `;` as separator dependent on operating system.

Comment: Yes, I tried a single JAR with a path relative to the directory I was running from.

Comment: Sorry, you have to explicitly specify the `ProperitesLauncher` to take effect. Try to change the command from
`java -Dloader.path=... -jar myjar.jar` to
`java -Dloader.path=xxx -Dloader.debug=true -cp myjar.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`.

Comment: That seemed to work, thanks!

Comment: I just reorganized the answer in comment to a formal and more detailed *Answer* below, for others to reference to easier. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spring Boot executable jar uses its own [ClassLoader created by a Launcher](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/Launcher.java#L49) at runtime. Classes loaded by System ClassLoader (specified by `-cp` classpaths) are not aware of classes inside the executable jar which are loaded by a child ClassLoader. Hence the ClassNotFoundException in your case.

Executable jars in `JAR` or `WAR` layout use simple `Launcher`s, that only care about classes packaged in the bundle. You have to use [`PropertiesLauncher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features) to instruct Spring Boot's ClassLoader to load your classes by specifying [`loader.path`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features) application property in either way:

### Method 1. Run PropertiesLauncher class directly:

```
$ java -Dloader.path=... -cp myjar.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher [args...]
```

This command will bypass the default Luncher (listed in the `Main-Class` entry in *myjar.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF*) in your executable jar/war and directly invoke the `PropertiesLauncher` class.

### Method 2. Set PropertiesLauncher as default (by using [`ZIP`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-configuration-layouts) layout)

**ZIP** layout, as described in [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-configuration-layouts):

> Similar to **JAR** layout, using `PropertiesLauncher`.

Packaged executable in the layout will by default look for `loader.*` properties, so you can run it just like:

```
$ java -Dloader.path=... -jar myjar.jar [args...]
```

For Maven projects, setting layout to ZIP in your POM.xml:

```xml
<project>
   <!-- ... -->
   <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <layout>ZIP</layout>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

For Gradle projects:

```
springBoot {
  layout = 'ZIP'
}
```

Comment: Additional note: generating a [fully executable jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/deployment-install.html) (by adding both `<executable>true</executable>` and `<layout>ZIP</layout>`) I had to use the environment variable `LOADER_PATH` instead of the `loader.path` property.